# Understanding the Taylor series of $|x-x+nd|^{-1}$ in Jackson's handling of the dipole-layer geometry

Tags: potential, classical-electrodynamics, dipole

On page 33 of Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics* (third edition), after obtaining the potential 
$$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_S \frac{\sigma(x')}{|x-x'|} \mathrm da' -  \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_S \frac{\sigma(x')}{|x-x' +nd|}\mathrm da''$$
he goes on and says:

> For small $d$ we can expand $|x-x+nd|^{-1}$. Consider the general expression $|x+a|^{-1}$, where $|a|\ll|x|$. We write a Taylor series expansion in three dimensions:
>   $$\frac{1}{x+a} = \frac{1}{x} + a \cdot \nabla \bigg( \frac{1}{x} \bigg) + \cdots$$

How does he get this expansion? Around what "point" he expands? I've been trying to find a way to get this expansion but no luck so far. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See e.g. [Wikipedia for Taylor's theorem for multivariate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Generalizations_of_Taylor.27s_theorem) for a more rigorous explanation.

In particular, for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the first order approximation around point $\vec{\xi}_0$ is:

$$
f(\vec{\xi}) \approx f(\vec{\xi}_0) + (\vec{\xi}-\vec{\xi}_0) \cdot (\nabla f) (\vec{\xi}_0).
$$

The intuition behind this is simply the fact that if $f$ is of 1st order (that is, $f(\vec{\xi}) = a + \vec{b} \cdot \vec{\xi}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$), this approximation is exact, and close to a point, the function can be approximated as a 1st order function.

In your example, $f(\vec{\xi}) = 1/|\vec{\xi}|$ and since we want to approximate the values of that close to $\vec{x}$, we choose  $\vec{\xi}_0 = \vec{x}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the  explanation. Are there other sources where I can read about it other then wikipedia? Even the title sounds shady in that article "multivariate functions" ... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Xsnac "Even the title sounds shady in that article"...what? Why does that sound shady? That's what it's called.